# Jump to implementation instead of declaration in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

In IntelliJ I can click on an symbol while holding the Ctrl key which will let IntelliJ (in case of methods) navigate to the declaration. This is documented [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Navigation_and_Search__Go_to_Declaration.html).
If the method was defined in an interface, IntelliJ will open that interface but not the implementation.

Is there a way to tell IntelliJ always jump to the implementation if there is at least one or make it asking me which I want to jump to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Navigate | Implementation(s)`, by default mapped to <kbd>Ctr/Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>left mouse button</kbd> I believe.